# Busqueda de Menor no funciona adecuadamente

Tags: c#

Estoy recién aprendiendo a usar C# en clases, y en un ejercicio de busqueda de mayores y menores (con procedimientos y vectores) son los menores que no entregan valor alguno y la verdad por más que lo reviso no encuentro la irregularidad que causa eso.

Omití parte del programa para que fuese más fácil de ver.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ID = new int[100];
            string[] Nombre = new string[100];
            int[] FdN = new int[100]; //FdN = Fecha de Nacimiento
            int[] FdI = new int[100]; //FdI = Fecha de Ingreso
            Int32[] Sueldo = new Int32[100];
            int[] NHE = new int[100]; //NH = Número de Horas Extras
            int[] NH = new int[100]; // NHE = Número de Hijos
            int[] VHE = new int[100]; //VHE = Valor Horas Extras

            int posicion = 0;
            int tamaño = 0;


            CargaVectores(ref tamaño, ref ID, ref Nombre, ref FdN, ref FdI, ref Sueldo, ref NHE, ref NH, ref VHE);

            Menu(ref ID, ref Nombre, ref posicion, ref tamaño, ref FdN, ref Sueldo, ref FdI, ref NH, ref NHE, ref VHE);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static void LeerReg(string Linea, ref int ID, ref string Nombre, ref int FdN, ref int FdI, ref Int32 Sueldo, ref int NHE, ref int NH, ref int VHE)
        {
            string linea = Linea;

            ID = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(0, 6));

            Nombre = linea.Substring(10, 20);

            FdN = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(40, 8));

            FdI = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(48, 8));

            Sueldo = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(56, 7));

            NHE = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(63, 2));

            NH = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(65, 1));

            VHE = Convert.ToInt32(linea.Substring(66, 5));
        }

        static void CargaVectores(ref int TamañoVectores, ref int[] ID, ref string[] Nombre, ref int[] FdN, ref int[] FdI, ref Int32[] Sueldo, ref int[] NHE, ref int[] NH, ref int[] VHE)
        {
            int nlinea = 1; //nlinea = número de linea
            StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("d:\\Datos\\Personal.txt");
            string Linea = "";

            while (Linea != null)
            {
                Linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                if (Linea != null)
                {
                    LeerReg(Linea, ref ID[nlinea], ref Nombre[nlinea], ref FdN[nlinea], ref FdI[nlinea], ref Sueldo[nlinea], ref NHE[nlinea], ref NH[nlinea], ref VHE[nlinea]);
                    Console.WriteLine("(" + nlinea + ")" + ID[nlinea] + " " + Nombre[nlinea] + " " + FdN[nlinea] + " " + FdI[nlinea] + " " + Sueldo[nlinea] + " " + NHE[nlinea] + " " + NH[nlinea] + " " + VHE[nlinea]);
                    nlinea = nlinea + 1;
                }
            }

            TamañoVectores = nlinea;
        }


        static void Menu(ref int[] ID, ref string[] Nombre, ref int posicion, ref int tamaño, ref int[] FdN, ref Int32[] Sueldo, ref int[] FdI, ref int[] NH, ref int[] NHE, ref int[] VHE)
        {
            bool Continuar = true;
            int op = 0; //op = opción
            int id = 0;
            while (Continuar == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n[Menú] \n 1) Identificación \n 2) Calcular Edad \n 3) Años en la Empresa \n 4) Mayor Sueldo \n 5) Menor Sueldo \n 6) Mayor Número de Horas Extra \n 7) Menor Número de Horas Extra \n 8) Mayor valor de Hora(s) Extra(s) pagada(s) \n 9) Menor valor de Hora(s) Extra(s) pagada(s) \n 10) Salir");


                while (op < 10)
                {
                    op = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n >Ingrese la opción que desea ver: ");
                    op = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.ReadKey();

                    while (op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4 && op != 5 && op != 6 && op != 7 && op != 8 && op != 9 && op != 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Comando no existente, ingrese uno nuevo");
                        op = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                    if (op == 5)
                    {
                        MenorSueldo(Sueldo, Nombre);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                }

            }
        }


        static void MenorSueldo(int[] Lista, string[] Nombre)
        {
            int ubi = 0;
            int menor = Lista[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Lista[i] < menor)
                {
                    menor = Lista[i];
                    ubi = i;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"El empleado con el menor sueldo es {Nombre[ubi]} con un valor de {menor}");

        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que siempre al ejecutar al opción 4 (o cualquiera que se busque el menor de un archivo) me imprime como: 
"El empleado con el menor sueldo es *[un espacio vacío]* con un valor de 0"

Lo cual más raro me parece, es que el procedimiento para buscar mayores no difiere en casi nada, pero funciona sin problemas.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda posible.

Comment: Cuando llamas a MenorSueldo, Lista y Nombre están completos? Porque en tu método no se ve nada raro

Comment: Sí, al menos creo que ese sería el caso, porque con el procedimiento de busqueda de mayor sí resulta;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error esta claro, en la función `CargaVectores` inicializas la variale `nlinea = 1` es decir insertas en la **posición 1 del vector** `Sueldo` y posteriormente cuando intentas calcular el mínimo empiezas por la **posición 0** cuyo valor inicial al no estar inicializado es **0**. Y como la comparación en la función MenorSueldo usas estrictamente menor `if (Lista[i] < menor)` salvo que menor sea negativo nunca va a entrar en el `if`.

En resumen bastaria con modificar la función `CargarVectores`quedando como sigue:

```
static void CargaVectores(ref int TamañoVectores, ref int[] ID, ref string[] Nombre, ref int[] FdN, ref int[] FdI, ref Int32[] Sueldo, ref int[] NHE, ref int[] NH, ref int[] VHE)
    {
        int nlinea = 0; //La primera posición del vector es la 0.
        StreamReader archivo = new StreamReader("d:\\Datos\\Personal.txt");
        string Linea = "";

        while (Linea != null)
        {
            Linea = archivo.ReadLine();
            if (Linea != null)
            {
                LeerReg(Linea, ref ID[nlinea], ref Nombre[nlinea], ref FdN[nlinea], ref FdI[nlinea], ref Sueldo[nlinea], ref NHE[nlinea], ref NH[nlinea], ref VHE[nlinea]);
                Console.WriteLine("(" + nlinea + ")" + ID[nlinea] + " " + Nombre[nlinea] + " " + FdN[nlinea] + " " + FdI[nlinea] + " " + Sueldo[nlinea] + " " + NHE[nlinea] + " " + NH[nlinea] + " " + VHE[nlinea]);
                nlinea = nlinea + 1;
            }
        }

        TamañoVectores = nlinea;
    }
```

Comment: Lo intenté, pero sigue sin dar los valores que necesito, ya que sigue sin imprimir al empleado, y con sueldo 0,

Comment: Ok, sí era en parte el "nlinea", también era el tamaño de los vectores que eran demasiado grandes, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta, debugear de esa manera:

```
static void MenorSueldo(int[] Lista, string[] Nombre)
        {
            int ubi = 0;
            int menor = Lista[0];

            foreach (var item in Lista)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);

            foreach (var item in Nombre)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);

            for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Lista[i] < menor)
                {
                    menor = Lista[i];
                    ubi = i;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado con el menor sueldo es {0} con un valor de {1}", Nombre[ubi], menor);
        }
```

Es decir, observar sí a la función los arrays llegan bien y también sí no es problema del WriteLine del final.

Saludos.

Comment: Tampoco me resultó, ¿pero cómo compruebo que los arrays llegan bien?
Supongo que por ahí estaría el problema, aunque como dije antes, con la busqueda del mayor no ocurre eso.

Comment: Con el código que pase, podes comprobar que los arrays llegan bien, iterando los arrays con el foreach e imprimiendo sus elementos.